# checkbox checked id and name value push array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I get proper and name values for checkbox by parent ng repeat. Problem is, when checked check box I need to push id and name values in one array. Also if uncheck remove that id and name values.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in partyList | filter:{ 'partyRole': 4}:true | filter:searchUsers |  mySlice:start:end">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="tableBox" value="{{user.partyId}}" name="{{user.first_name}}" ng-checked="userBox" ng-model="userModel" ng-change="getIndex(user.partyId,user.first_name,userModel)" />
          </td>

          <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.phone_number}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: ng-model should be unique. if you repeating the ng-model is not generic.

Comment: @SudharsanS Agreed! +1